# Opacity of font not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to apply an opacity to the text rendered on a d3 pie chart - fill seems to be rendering ok but opacity not - this is the snippet where I am attempting to apply the opacity:

```
  var txts = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "theTxts")
    .attr("dx", 10) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
    .attr("dy", 18) //Move the text down
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return "#theArc_" + i;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("opacity", 0.0001)
    .style("fill", "#000");

  txts.transition()
    .duration(1400)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "#000");
```

Here is a full working example of the visual:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VU85z7zz50PN4geTbf4F?p=preview

Comment: The opacity is working. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm hoping to transition the text from completely see-through to solid text: but when the text first appears it looks solid to me?

Comment: I'm not seeing that. Look at the code with a higher duration: https://plnkr.co/edit/HciInY7yRJOWXKURsj7Q?p=preview

Comment: you think you can see a 50ms transition!!?? @whytheq you must think you have great vision!!

Comment: @JaromandaX its not 50ms, it's 1.4 sec. That 50ms value is for the tooltip.

Comment: oh, sorry!!! that's the only text transition I found in that code :p

Comment: The `opacity` property applies to *container elements* and *graphics elements* only. The `<textPath>` on the other hand is a *text content (child) element*. You need to style the surrounding `<text>` instead, which is a *graphics element*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado on ff, on my laptop, it is just full black for the whole 6 seconds. let me try in IE

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ok - so it seems to be browswer related - I can see the opacity transition in IE but not in FF. Any suggestions for a different approach that might do the same thing?

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for the comment - how do I go about implementing your suggestion?

Comment: @altocumulus I sussed it using your suggestion and posted the code as answer - if you want to post an additional answer just with a couple of extra d3 tips I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the SVG spec has it, the [`opacity`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#OpacityProperty) property

> *Applies to:*     [container elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermContainerElement) (except [**‘mask’**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#MaskElement)) and [graphics elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement)

As it turns out, the [`<textPath>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextPathElement) is neither of both. It belongs to the categories [*text content element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermTextContentElement) and [*text content child element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermTextContentChildElement) and can, therefore, not be styled using the `opacity`attribute.

You need to style the surrounding [`<text>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) instead, which is a [*graphics element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement) as well as a [*text content element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermTextContentElement), which makes it styleable using `opacity`.

For your code you need to define the initial opacity on the `<text>`s to which you keep a reference `txts`. Afterwards, the `<textPath>`s are appended to the `<text>`s using this reference. There is no need keep a reference to the `<textPath>` elements themselves, though, as they are not referenced anywhere else. Your transition to the final opacity value will then be created for the `<text>` using that same reference created earlier.

```
var txts = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
  .data(partition.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class", "theTxts")
    .attr("dx", 10) 
    .attr("dy", 18) 
    .style("opacity", 0.0001)  // Define initial opacity on the <text>s
    .style("fill", "#000");
  
txts                           // Append <textPaths>s. No need to keep the reference
  .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return "#theArc_" + i;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
    
txts.transition()              // Transition the original <text>s to new opacity value
  .duration(1400)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "#000");
```

Have a look at the updated [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JfUWia16lUF6NnFpKcxO?p=preview) for a working demo.

#### Future outlook—SVG 2

The above will change, however, once the upcoming SVG 2 becomes an official W3C recommendation and is implemented by all browsers. As of version 2 the [`textPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextPathElement) element becomes a *graphics element* itself making it styleable using the `opacity` property. The snippet below may help to determine whether your browser implements the `textPath` element according to SVG 2:

```js
console.log(
  SVGGraphicsElement &&     // Part of SVG 2; not available in IE 11
  document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath")
    instanceof SVGGraphicsElement
);
```

This will print `true`, if your browser implements SVG 2's version of `textPath` implementing the [`SVGGraphicsElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) interface, which itself is new to SVG 2. For me this prints `true` in both Chrome 56 and FF 51, but `false` in IE 11.

Comment: Thanks for this full answer. The one small addition is that my original code actually worked when run in MS Edge browser - maybe that browser makes some assumptions and passes the opacity change from the child upwards?

Comment: @whytheq I think this behavior is in advance of the upcoming SVG 2 standard where the `textPath` element will eventually also be graphics element. Have a look at the [draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextPathElement) for more detailed information.

Comment: OP's original code is working in Chrome (which, for me, is synonym of browser) as well. That's why I made the first comment ("the opacity is working") in the question.

Comment: @whytheq The original code works for me on Windows in Chrome 56 as well as in FF 51, but not in IE 11. To check if a browser implements the relevant changes for the `textPath` element you may execute `SVGGraphicsElement && document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath") instanceof SVGGraphicsElement` in your browser's console. This returns `true` for my versions of Chrome and FF, but `false` for IE 11. I'd expect this to return `true` for Edge as well. Could you check this?

Comment: @altocumulus not sure this helps as it returns true in my FF but the original code doesn't work in my FF. In Edge it returns undefined.

Comment: Hm, not sure about FF. Maybe it's your specific version as it works for me. But the expression should definitely never return undefined; it's got to be a Boolean. Have you copied the **whole** expression to Edge? Also, what does it print, if you execute the snippet I added to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments to the question I found via Geraldo's comment that my unwanted behaviour was only happening on ff and the transition was ok on ie.

Then I used altocumulus comment to create an extra variable for the text element. Code now looks like this:

```
  var txts = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "theTxts")
    .attr("dx", 10) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
    .attr("dy", 18) //Move the text down

  var txtPth =txts.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return "#theArc_" + i;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill", "#000");

  txts.transition()
    .duration(7000)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "#000");
```

Transition works fine now on both IE and FF. Working plunk:

https://plnkr.co/edit/mra4PHUn057LZxcFZUgI?p=preview